# Warning : “Set this option from the IDE menu instead” in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I'm studying the Chapter "Imp" of Software foundation. I runned the command `Unset Printing Coercions.` in Coq Ide, the coq Message warned me that `"Set this option from the IDE menu instead"` and obviously the command doesn't work. I guess maybe this command will work in the Coq prompt environment, But I want to know what I should do if I want to use "Unset Printing" command in Coq Ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go under the "View" menu, and tick/untick the "Display coercions" button.